# Missing Sec-WebSocket-Key in WebSocket connection handshake

Tags: firefox, websocket, chromium

Since yesterday we have had a problem with WebSocket connections. The chromium-based browser and also Firefox don't add `Sec-WebSocket-Key` into the headers during connection. We use the standard `new WebSocket()` to connect with the server.

[image: Connection]

Missing header `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header
[image: Missing header]

Funny thing is that when I open a new incognito window I can create a connection but after some `fetch()` request if I will try to make another connection it will fail - missing `Sec-Websocket-Key` header.

1. First WebSocket connection - success
   [image: First WebSocket connection - success]
2. Fetch request - app health status
   [image]
3. Failed WebSockect connection after a fetch request
   [image: Failed WebSockect connection after a fetch request]
   Second WebSocket connection - missing `Sec-WebSocket-Key`
   [image: Second WebSocket connection details - missing Sec-Websocket-Key]

Nginx config for `/ws`.

```
    location ^~ /ws {                                                                                                                      
        proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                                     
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                     
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";                                                               
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;                           
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;            
        proxy_pass http://backend;  
    }
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Checked in Google Chrome Version 96.0.4664.93 and Firefox 95.0.1 Windows, Linux and Mac.

MacOS & Safari works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the HTTP2 implementation in Firefox & Chrome  (Safari works OK). We were digging for three days and finally realized that after disabling the HTTP2 issue disappeared.

This is the response from DigitalOcean technical support:

> We had recently enabled support for Websockets over HTTP2 (RFC 8441).
> This adds support for browsers to reuse an existing HTTP2 connection
> and will allow tunneling of WebSocket connections over an HTTP2
> stream. As part of an immediate fix we have disabled this
> functionality which informs browsers to create Websockets over HTTP1.1
> (RFC 6455). We believe the bug is actually within Chrome/Firefox but
> further testing is necessary to track down the issue. To our knowledge
> the LB wasn't the issue as it was the browser that was not including
> the required header Sec-WebSocket-Key.

Comment: AFAIK RFC 8441 does not require to add Sec-WebSocket-Key. If the LB translates HTTP/2 into HTTP/1.1 then it should add it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem.

- Our CDN was returning `SETTINGS_ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL:1` to the client, which [indicates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8441.html#section-3) that WebSockets over HTTP/2 (RFC 8441) is supported.
- So Chrome tried to connect with WebSockets over HTTP/2 but failed, because our backend service didn't support RFC 8441.

  - `Sec-WebSocket-Key` is [not required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8441.html#section-5) in RFC 8441. The problem was that Chrome tried to use WebSockets over HTTP/2. `Sec-WebSocket-Key` missing is just one aspect of it.
- The error occurred occasionally because:

  - When HTTP/3 is available, Chrome [tries to establish](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/proto-quic/c/igD7dLSct24) both HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 connections, and the one which "wins the race" would actually be used.
  - When HTTP/2 won, the connection failed as explained above.
  - When HTTP/3 won, WebSockets over HTTP/1.1 was used and the connection succeeded.

    - Didn't dig into this. Probably our CDN didn't send `SETTINGS_ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL:1` over HTTP/3.
- It worked in Safari because Safari doesn't support WebSockets over HTTP/2 and always uses HTTP/1.1.

We made a contact to our CDN provider, they disabled `SETTINGS_ENABLE_CONNECT_PROTOCOL:1`, and the error stopped occurring.